# Why didn't the number of answers get updated after the deletion of any answer?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, deleted-answers

I am little bit curious about the data that is showing the number of answers of the particular question.

I just saw that there were two answers on one of the posts; one is mine and one of the other. He deleted his answer and even after more than *8 minutes* the number of answers that is showing there is *2*. I am not sure why it is because I think it should be *1*.

This is what I observed.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a link to the question?

Comment: It happens on any question, though... The number of answers is always the total of all answers, deleted or not (for 10k+ users)

Comment: @Linuxios: Here you go:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18795006/css-tables-colspan

Comment: @nhahtdh ohh I didn't know about this actually, Just now I tried to see the same question on another browser where I were not logged in and there it is showing `1 Answer`. Thanks again :)

Comment: @nhahtdh is right. I get 2 answers too, and I'm >10k.

Comment: Relevant FAQ: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/335251)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because there are two answers *visible to you*.

When you delete something, it's not really gone from the database. You and other users with 10000 reputation or more can still see it (and users with 20000+ rep can vote to undelete it).

The answer count simply states how many answers exist - that you can see.

If you have less than 10000 reputation, and delete your answer, the answer count won't go down. (If someone else deletes their answer it will though, because you wouldn't be able to see it anymore.)

Comment: 10k+ can cast undelete vote, at least that is what I remembered from when I was still < 20k. Is there any change recently?

Comment: @nhahtdh 10k+ can undelete questions, but not answers. This has always been true, IIRC.

Comment: Oh, right. I just checked the privilege wiki.