# Number of answers not consistent for users with over 10k rep

Tags: bug

Say a question has 8 answers to it, with 3 deleted.

On the main page users with over 10,000 rep see the question labeled with 5 answers, however when they enter the question, it is labeled with 8 answers.

Is this a bug?

Shouldn't this be consistent?

Comment: @psubsee2003 - the answer over there doesn't address my question at all. I'm saying that the labels are *inconsistent*

Comment: Sorry... missed that part.  that's a different duplicate.

Comment: see also: sub-10k users often see 'active today' without there being any (visible to them) activity today.

Comment: @psubsee2003 hmm, so it seems like the question has been asked, but I don't think much of the accepted answer there. Q: Why is there an inconsistency A: There is an inconsistency...

Comment: @Danield then put a bounty on that question if you want a better answer.  This one is a duplicate and we try to avoid duplicate bug reports.  Effectively the answer is it is [meta-tag:status-bydesign].  The reason is that fact that you have 10K rep.  The question page only shows the undeleted answer count.  It isn't until you look at the question do you actually see the undelete + deleted answer count.

Answer (score 3):

I think the OP is absolutely correct, this is a case of inconsistency. The point would be to show the correct number of answers, no matter what. Although I do not know how much work this is in the code of course

But "seeing that there were **additional** answers" as Stijn argues is not really correct I think, you should see how many answers there are, and deleted answers are answers after all. So I'd argue that the correct number is the total number of answers

But it's a minor problem indeed

Comment: I read the question a bit too fast, reading "when they enter the question, it has 8 answers". [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196930/why-number-of-answer-didnt-get-update-after-the-deletion-of-any-answer) it also says that the label on the question includes deleted answers [tag:by-design], so it seems you're right.